# Joomla 2.5: Javascript code don't work

Tags: javascript, joomla

Hi in my Joomla arcicle written using JCE editor (where I enabled Javascript code) I added this code to use and accordion panel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var layerdiv = new Fx.Accordion($$('.titolo'), $$('.blocco_da_espandere'),      {
        display: -1,
        alwaysHide: 1,
        onActive: function(toggler) {
            toggler.setStyle('color', '#ff0000');
        },
        onBackground: function(toggler) {
            toggler.setStyle('color', '#0000ff');
        }
    });
});
// ]]>
```

```
<div class="titolo">Clicca qui</div>
<div class="blocco_da_espandere" style="padding:10px;border-left:3px solid #ff0000;">Buongiorno.<br />Io sono il blocco espanso. Mi auguro che la tua giornata sia piacevole.<br /> In caso contrario, me ne farò una ragione.</div>
```

but in my page I see the content of the div but not the effect.

Comment: Dont add Javascript to the article without using a plugin such as [Sourcerer](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer)

Comment: But it's safe this plugin?

Comment: You cannot add javascript to joomla article from article manager. For this you can create a simple content plugin or use existing plugins.

Comment: Yes I can add Javascript to Jooma Article with JCE (in the advanced option I can allow Javascript code)

Comment: Yes the plugin is extremely safe. It's developed by one the the most popular Joomla extensions developers

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to accomplish but the page break plugin gives you the option to use sliders or tabs when dividing up content by inserting page breaks.

Comment: This may help you http://www.walkswithme.net/how-to-include-html-or-php-codes-into-joomla-article

Comment: Do you have any console error? This accordion needs Mootools "More" and "Core" - http://jsfiddle.net/FTLcE/

Comment: NO I haven't console error. I see in my page the content of the two div

Comment: I installed the pulign Sourcerer but in my wharp template framework doesn't work. With another template this pulugin work fine.